# how can i show loader until the result is ready in Angular and bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

Im calling a API which takes a few secons to get the response :

```
   this.http.get(`http://localhost:44301/consentinitiation/${this.qid}`)
    .pipe(retryWhen(_ => {
    return interval(1000)
    }))
   .subscribe(result => {result
   this.qrcodelink=result["qrCodeLink"];
    this.isDisplayed=true;
     })
```

on my HTML component I have a qrcode which is loading:

```
    <div *ngIf="isDisplayed">
        <qr-code [value]="qrcodelink"  ></qr-code>  
      </div>
```

I need to put the loader here,I have found bootstrap loader tag

```
  <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
 <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
 </div>
```

How can i use it?

Comment: What you could do is use a HTTP interceptor in Angular, there are plenty of medium articles about this, and it is a lot to explain, so I would advice you to read up on Http Interceptor loading examples and I'm sure you will be able to fix it :). https://medium.com/swlh/angular-loading-spinner-using-http-interceptor-63c1bb76517b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the `isDisplayed` field to display the loading:

```html
<div *ngIf="!isDisplayed" class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
 <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div>
```

Also maybe reset the displayed when making a new call with a `tap`

```js
this.http
  .get(`http://localhost:44301/consentinitiation/${this.qid}`)
  .pipe(
    retryWhen((_) => interval(1000)),
    tap(() => (this.isDisplayed = false)),
  )
  .subscribe((result) => {
    this.qrcodelink = result['qrCodeLink'];
    this.isDisplayed = true;
  });
```

Comment: but what if i want to start showing the loade when i click the button?

Comment: Which button? I don't see any buttons in your question; I can only answer to what I see :-) You can always create another field and assign it to true/false whenever you want

Answer (score 0):

Show the spinner while you're waiting for the server response.

With bootstrap it's pretty easy to create a spinner that takes up the whole page and doesn't show the other elements.
You can try like this:

```html
<div *ngIf="!isDisplayed"
  class="position-fixed w-100 h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center bg-white spinner-overlay">
  <div class=" text-center">
    <div class="spinner-border mb-1 text-primary" role="status"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

These are all bootstrap classes except for spinner-overlay which does nothing more than set the z-index property.

```html
.spinner-overlay {
    z-index: 2000;
}
```

After you get the server response just set this.isDisplayed = true;